# 2 simple array errors?

Tags: java, arrays

I created a method that needs to check the range of a multidimensional array and make sure each value in the 2D array is smaller than or equal to the length of the array.

```
public static boolean method(int[][] solution){
        //check rows for 1-N
        for (int i=0; i < solution.length; i++){
                if (solution[i] > solution.length)
                return false; //check rows
            }

        //check columns for 1 - N
        for (int j = 0; j<solution.length; j++){
            //get a column in the one dimensional array
            int[] column = new int[solution.length];
            for (int i=0; i < solution.length; i++){
                column[i] = solution[i][j];
            }
            if (column[i] > solution.length)
                return false; //check columns

        }
    return true;
    }
```

However, the errors I receive are follows:

```
Program.java:99: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
                                if (solution[i] > solution.length)
                                                ^
  first type:  int[]
  second type: int
Program.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
                        if (column[i] > solution.length)
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class Program
2 errors
```

Perhaps for the first error i need to get the array value instead of comparing the array? Not sure..

Answer (score 4):

First, you can't compare an array with an `int` value

```
if (solution[i] > solution.length) // solution is a 2-d array and thus solution[i] is a 1-d array
// which can't be compared with an int value
```

and second, the `i` was declared in the `for` loop, and thus it's not visible outside its scope.

```
for (int i=0; i < solution.length; i++){
    column[i] = solution[i][j];
} // scope of i is over here
if (column[i] > solution.length) // that's why you can't access `i` here
    return false;
```

You either need to use `j` or declare the `i` before the `for`, so that you can use it after it or probably, move the `if` inside the inner `for` loop(and that seems to be the right way for your problem as well).

Comment: i thought solution[i] is comparing the value inside the array to the int?

Comment: oh what a dumb mistake on the second error. sorry its been a long night

Comment: so how can i compare the value INSIDE the array to the interger value solution.length?

Comment: I'm really not sure what the first `for` loop does. Can you tell what exactly you want to do, so that I can suggest accordingly?!

Comment: I feel that the first `for` is not at all required, as you don't need to compare `rows` separately as such. With 2 nested `for` loops, you can iterate over all the rows & columns of the 2-d array and do the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `i` outside the `for` loop, maybe you want to use `j` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its because, `solution` is a 2d array.

```
int[][] solution;
```

and to get this work it should be,

```
if(solution[][] > solution.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this much code should suffice

```
public static boolean method(int[][] solution) {
    // check rows for 1-N
    for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < solution[i].length; i++) {
            if (solution[i][j] > solution.length)
                return false; // check rows
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: that's correct. but i was trying to follow something in my book.